# Accessing a specific element of HasMap of String & ArrayList

Tags: arraylist, hashmap

I was using an array double xyz[20000][20000] in my project but java is giving "Heap Space" error. I am planning to use Hashmaps instead of the above array. So I need to use Hashmap .
Now the question is that as with java array if an element needs to be accessed we can access it like xyz[10][10], but if I use the above Hashmap then how can i access a specific element like key=10 and the 10th element in the respective array?

Answer (score 0):

HashMap always works that way. You have specified functions in the HashMap class in java to get values of a key, `getKey()` and `getValue()` should get you the key and values of the respective key.

```
Map<int, List<Integer>> entry = new HashMap<int, List<Integer>>();
//rest of the code, putting values etc.
//the accessing data of 10th index
int key = entry.getKey();
List<Integer> values = entry.getValue();
System.out.println("Key = " + key);
System.out.println("Values = " + values.get(10) + "\n");
```